# What happens if offset specified by kafka consumer is not present in Broker?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am new to kafka. I want to understand how kafka consumer behaves when offset specified by it is not present. Maybe the message at the given offset is deleted due to retention policy or consumer specified an invalid offset value.

Answer (score 5):

Your consumer will use your [`auto.offset.reset`](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) setting to reset its offset to a valid position. If no reset option has been specified, then the Broker will throw an [`InvalidOffsetException`](https://kafka.apache.org/0110/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/common/errors/InvalidOffsetException.html).

Comment: `auto.offset.reset=latest` is the default. See @sureshsiva's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the [auto.offset.reset](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs)'s mode that you have configured. Please find below about what will happen with each mode when you seek to an offset that doesn't exist in the given topic's partition.

**auto.offset.reset=earliest**

- Partition's offset will be reset to 0 and all messages will be consumed
  [image]

**auto.offset.reset=latest**

- Partition's offset will be reset to the last known offset and will be consuming only the new messages
  [image]

**auto.offset.reset=none**

- Consumer application will fail with [OffsetOutOfRangeException](https://kafka.apache.org/21/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/OffsetOutOfRangeException.html) as shown below,
  [image]

Comment: Default for `auto.offset.reset` is `latest`